# Why I can't use GIT from Eclipse ? I can't do GIT operations on my project files (EGit plugin installed)

Tags: eclipse, git, ide, egit

this is my first time using GIT inside Eclipse (I always used from IntelliJ or console) but I am finding some difficulties trying to configure it.

I am following this official tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#git-support-for-eclipse

I have correctly installed the GIT plugin into my Eclipse.

If I open the **GIT Repositories** perspective (as shown in the tutorial) it works fine and here I see the repository defined in my project (the only GIT project that I have in my workspace at this time).

The problem is that going into my **Package explorer** I can't see the indicators of the files status (if something is changed and have to be committed, if there are conflict, etcetc), as explained in the tutorial.

At the same time it seems that I can't do GIT operation on these files (for example add a file to the staging are). Selecting a file and doing **right click --> Team** I have no GIT reference, this is what I have:

[image]

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I correctly use GIT from my Eclipse?

Comment: Right click the project root and see if there is `Team` -> `Share Project` available.

Comment: @Kai Tnx it seems to works. If you open as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project root and see if there is `Team` -> `Share Project`